# POM error: Failure to find com.redhat.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:pom:1.3.2.Final-redhat-00001 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2

Tags: maven, apache-kafka, quarkus

I'm trying to learn more about kafka streams and quarkus and I'm trying to deploy a sample stream app from github https://github.com/kgshukla/data-streaming-kafka-quarkus
However, every time I run quarkus I get the following error. I checked the pom.xml but i don't see anything wrong with it. I cloned the sample app directly from the repo and didn't make any changes

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.redhat.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:pom:1.3.2.Final-redhat-00001 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 23, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:jar is missing. @ line 33, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5:jar is missing. @ line 37, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar is missing. @ line 42, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-kafka-client:jar is missing. @ line 47, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-spring-web:jar is missing. @ line 51, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-kafka-streams:jar is missing. @ line 55, column 17
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.acme:quarkus-kafka-streaming:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/mariahito/Desktop/quarkus-apps/kafka-docker/data-streaming-kafka-quarkus/quarkus-kafka-streaming/pom.xml) has 7 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.redhat.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:pom:1.3.2.Final-redhat-00001 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 23, column 19 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:jar is missing. @ line 33, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5:jar is missing. @ line 37, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar is missing. @ line 42, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-kafka-client:jar is missing. @ line 47, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-spring-web:jar is missing. @ line 51, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-kafka-streams:jar is missing. @ line 55, column 17
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
(base) Marias-MBP:quarkus-kafka-streaming mariahito$ ./mvnw quarkus:dev
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.redhat.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:pom:1.3.2.Final-redhat-00001 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 23, column 19
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:jar is missing. @ line 33, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5:jar is missing. @ line 37, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar is missing. @ line 42, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-kafka-client:jar is missing. @ line 47, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-spring-web:jar is missing. @ line 51, column 17
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-kafka-streams:jar is missing. @ line 55, column 17
 @ 
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.acme:quarkus-kafka-streaming:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/mariahito/Desktop/quarkus-apps/kafka-docker/data-streaming-kafka-quarkus/quarkus-kafka-streaming/pom.xml) has 7 errors
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable import POM: Failure to find com.redhat.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:pom:1.3.2.Final-redhat-00001 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced @ line 23, column 19 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:jar is missing. @ line 33, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5:jar is missing. @ line 37, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.rest-assured:rest-assured:jar is missing. @ line 42, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-kafka-client:jar is missing. @ line 47, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-spring-web:jar is missing. @ line 51, column 17
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for io.quarkus:quarkus-kafka-streams:jar is missing. @ line 55, column 17
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Answer (score 0):

That example uses the product version (i.e supported by Red Hat) of Quarkus.
That version is not available in Maven Central.

You can just drop the redhat-00001 part of the version and you should be fine.

But I would also suggest using a newer version of Quarkus. 1.3 is about a year old.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem. I searched on [Maven Central Repo Search](https://search.maven.org/) for ' quarkus-universe-bom ' and obtained [List of quarkus-universe-bom available](https://search.maven.org/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom). I updated from 1.8 to 1.13.1.Final, directly, and nothing seems to be broken.

Hope this may help, good luck.